# Running grunt package aborted due to warning

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

When I try to run the grunt package on my angular.js folder there are warnings.

```
C:\Users\Admin\angular.js>grunt package

Running "shell:npm-install" (shell) task
Warning: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "scripts\npm\install-dependencies.sh"
Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Comment: Run it with `--verbose` to see what the error is.

Comment: Hi sir when I run it with --verbose..These are the error..                                                                         Running "shell:npm-install" (shell) task
Verifying property shell.npm-install exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: stdout, stderr, stdin, failOnError, stdinRawMode=false
Command: scripts\npm\install-dependencies.sh
Warning: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "scripts\npm\install-
dependencies.sh"
 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Comment: Are you able to run shell scripts on your Windows machine?

Comment: Your Grunt file should have a `default`. Is it defined? Check that as well. and run the `cmd prompt` as Admin and try.

Comment: Before I run the grunt package sir, I run npm-install and bower install for dependencies and components..It is the npm-install problem maybe?

Comment: @EshwarPrasadYaddanapudi yes sir I run it via administrator the same problem also

Comment: Hi sir I already solve this problem by adding --force to run the grunt package. thanks anyway :))